# Were there Sith wielding non-red lightsabers?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, sith, lightsaber

So, did some Sith wield a non-red (non-synthetic) lightsaber?

And the other way around, were there some Jedi wielding red ones?

Comment: Are you looking for canon only, or is Legends acceptable? The answer you've gotten so far contains Legends information (and the part about Sidious' reincarnation is almost certainly going to contradict canon once Episode VII comes out).

Answer (score 13):

### TL;DR

In EU: Exar Kun, Darth Vader and Darth Sidious

In Canon: Anakin Skywalker

---

## We know of three

[Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith_lightsaber#Mechanics_and_Distinguishing_Features) explains that:

> However, the bloodshine blades were not universal to all Sith, with
>   notables such as **Exar Kun** and **Darth Vader** continuing to favor their
>   blue Jedi lightsabers after defecting. However, **Kun was likely unaware
>   of the custom, and Vader replaced his Jedi weapon with a red-bladed
>   Sith saber soon afterwards**. **Darth Sidious** also used a pale blue
>   colored lightsaber after his reincarnation. Ultimately, **Sith who
>   wielded colors other than red were usually looking to disguise their
>   dark affiliations**. In fact, Palpatine was of the opinion that the Sith
>   Lords had outgrown the use of lightsabers, and only continued to use
>   them to humiliate the Jedi.

So, **yes, non-synthetic lightsabers have been used by Sith Lords**, but not for extended periods, or not intentionally done so to disregard the custom.

We know that there were probably more than just three, as Kun's

> followers opted instead to continue using their Jedi lightsabers in combat, though at least one follower used a lightsaber with a red crystal

([Source](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lightsaber))

More specifically, **in canon, we have only seen one: Anakin Skywalker**

More generally though, as to why most Sith use a red lightsaber is explained in the same article as follows:

> the defining feature of Sith lightsabers was **the use of synthetic
>   crystals**, as opposed to the Adegan and Ilum crystals favored by the
>   Jedi. **Almost all synthetic crystals used by the Sith featured a red
>   coloration**

The article goes on to explain that:

> Originally, Sith Lords utilized synthetic crystals due to their lack
>   of access to the traditional sites where crystals were harvested, as
>   these were frequented by the Jedi Order. Eventually, the use of these
>   synth-crystals became a tradition amongst the Sith, who believed the
>   creation of a crystal suited to one's own needs was a display of
>   strength over the Jedi, who relied on the "untamed wilds of space" to
>   provide.[5]
>
> **The red coloration was also a result of the forging process, though it
>   too came to become a tradition.** The aggressive crimson hue served to
>   differentiate the Sith from their sworn enemies; the Jedi, who
>   typically utilized softer colors, commonly blue or green

Comment: I wish I could've said 'We know of two' - you know: the rule of two!

Comment: The answer is "These guys"

Comment: @OrangeDog: Someone needs to add that to [the list](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1289/the-many-memes-of-scifi-stackexchange).

Comment: @RedCaio Done 

Answer (score 5):

In addition of Often Right's answer, in Legends video games, we can see Sith and Dark Jedi wearing:

- yellow blades (Yun from Jedi Knight: Dark Forces II)
- orange blades (Pic and Gorc, still in Jedi Knight)
- blue blades (Sariss in Jedi Knight)
- purple blades (Boc in Jedi Knight and Reborn in Jedi Knight II/Jedi Academy, various Sith in Knights of the Old Republic)

If you want to limit to Sith only and not Dark Jedi, you still got red and purple lightsabers.

Comment: There's also Kreia and the floating purple sabers...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers

- Vergere used a Yellow lightsaber
- Lumiya used a yellow light whip (if you want to count that since it isn't technically a lightsaber)
- Grievous had two Blue and two Green lightsabers (although he wasn't technically a Sith or even a force user)

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely!

Red is the most frequent color because it is made with a synthetic crystal which is easier to obtain, and you know most dark side users always go for the path of least resistance.

However, there are Sith using other colors, and dark jedi as well.

Anyway, I wrote an in-depth post on [sith lightsabers](http://instageeked.com/2015/09/29/why-are-sith-lightsabers-red-the-answer-is-simple/) that I think may be useful, but this pretty much sums it up.

EDIT: Summarizing the info on the source link in case it goes bad:

- Sith's Focusing Crystals are Synthetic:
  Synth crystals began by being red, and with time technology developed and allowed sith to forge any color, but red was already implemented now and it became a tradition.
- Red symbolizes rage and there's info (non-cannon due to Disney purchasing Lucas Arts) that it pulls users to the dark side, so there's a connection to the dark side of the force.
- Sith and Dark Jedi want people to fear them as soon as they draw their blade, so they adopt colors that easily identify them as dark and dangerous.
- The info on the source link is in-depth, but it is basically this when you sum it up :)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Good answers contain the useful information in them, rather than simply including a link. Links can go bad etc. so maybe edit your answer to include the detail you feel answer the question. :) More info: [tour] and [help].

Comment: It's worth noting that Sith don't use synthetic crystals because they are easier to obtain but rather because synthetic crystals are actually stronger than natural ones.